# Solr contextual query boosting

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr and I would like to boost my results with a contextual parameter.

For example, in a simple case, admit my documents are :

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "list":[]
}
{
 "id": "2",
 "list": ["3"]
}
...
```

If I have a query like for example :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/MyCore/select?q=*:*&contextParam=3
```

I would like to boost all documents which list contains the contextParam.

I already use the edismax parser to boost documents on other fields like dates but right now I can't access this optional parameter.

Thank you !

Comment: Please read the description of the tag before you use it -- this question has nothing to do with [boost c++ libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/boost/info).

Comment: so, what did you try edismax parser already?

Comment: Sorry I am a new participant here.

I figured out the solution, in case that would help anyone (using the Solr admin tool) :
If i have in the Raw Query Parameters :
    contextParam="3"
I can put in the bq the query "list:${contextParam}" in order to boost the documents where the list contains the contextParam value